# Napili - Customize Topic Detail Page Based on Selected Topic

Tags: community, napili, topics

I'm setting up a community using the Napili template. I'd like to use the Featured Topics component on my home page, but I'm having trouble with it. When I click on a topic from that component, it sends me to the Topic Detail page for that related Topic. **I'd like to be able to customize the components/structure of the Topic Detail page based on which topic is clicked.** For example, I want to show a different Headline for each topic, and for one my topics, I want to use a Case List component, while the others use an Article List component.

This doesn't seem to be possible and the structure, components, and and heading of the page are the same across all of my topics. Any idea how to direct to more customized pages when using the Featured Topics component?